# "Interrupted function call" exception in time.sleep() with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, sleep, pywin32

We have a Python script running nightly, on Windows, which occasionally polls a server, and then goes to sleep for about 30 minutes, using [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep).

Most of the time this works fine, but occasionally we get

```
00:49:48 Sleeping for 29.7765000025 minutes, for a total delay of 30 minutes
00:49:48 Traceback (most recent call last):
00:49:48   File "somescript.py", line 15, in <module>
00:49:48     print(somemodule.wait_for_execution_success(someguid, poll_time_in_minutes=5))
00:49:48   File "somemodule.py", line 82, in wait_for_execution_success
00:49:48     time.sleep(poll_time_in_minutes*60)
00:49:48 IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted function call
```

What could be the cause of this?  And even more important, how can we avoid this?

I could just wrap it with `try:` `except IOError: pass` of course, but somehow that feels like a workaround.

The only thing I could find on the interwebs was to try and switch to `win32api.Sleep()` from the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) module.  (I can't find no documentation, but [the source code](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/1a236fcc5ccd8f3a24e1dd8b76633e33e2dcaa62/win32/src/win32apimodule.cpp#L4751) together with Microsoft's documentation on the underlying [SleepEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepex) suggest I should just call `win32api.Sleep(30*60*1000)`.)  But I don't like to have an additional dependency.  And more importantly, would that fix the above issue?

(This is with Python 2.7.14, if it matters.)

Comment: This might not happen anymore since Python 3.5, because Python docs [say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep): "_Changed in version 3.5:- The function now sleeps at least secs even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal, except if the signal handler raises an exception (see [PEP 475](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0475) for the rationale)."

Answer (score 4):

The family of `sleep` functions can return early because of some external event.

In principle, the approach to this problem is to work out the time you want to wake up, and then call sleep based on how far away that time point is. If you get an EINTR exception, just sleep again with a revised duration based on the current time.

Comment: Yes, and the documentation mentions that possibility of returning early. But this is an _early exception_. So you indeed suggest to just catch `IOError`?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster Yes, catch the error make make sure it's EINTR. If it is EINTR, repeat the sleep with a revised duration. If it is some other error then you should rethrow.

Comment: With apologies for the formatting, you are suggesting to do

`import errno
try:
        time.sleep(somedelay)
except IOError as ex:
        if ex.errno != errno.EINTR: raise`

?  Is that how I make sure it's EINTR?

Comment: That looks correct, but I'm not a Pythonista. If you put that in a loop, checking for the arrival of your deadline and calculate `somedelay` at the top you should be done.